# Select the min time between 2 hours in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my full query:

```html
update dbo.Sheet
set arrival_date =convert(varchar(10),date , 101)
update dbo.Sheet 
       set arival_day =convert(varchar(10),time , 108) 
update dbo.Sheet 
       set leaving_date =convert(varchar(10),date , 101)
update dbo.Sheet
       set leaving_day=convert(varchar(10),time , 108)


     

       
 

       
select tFullName
       ,arrival_date
       ,(select  min(arival_day) from dbo.Sheet group by arrival_date having datepart(hh,min(arival_day))  not between 00 and 05)
      ,case when datepart(hh,min(arival_day))  between 00 and 05 then  (select  min(arival_day) from dbo.Sheet where datepart(hh,arival_day)  not between 00 and 05 ) 
         else min(arival_day)   
    end arrival_time
    
   , case when  lead(datepart(hh,min(arival_day)),1,0)over (order by tfullname) between 00 and 04
   then lead(leaving_date,1,leaving_date) over (order by tfullname) 
   else leaving_date end leaving_date
     
   ,case when lead(datepart(hh,min(arival_day)),1,0)over (order by tfullname) between 00 and 04
   then lead((select max(arival_day) from dbo.Sheet where datepart(hh,arival_day) between 00 and 05 group by leaving_date) ,1,max(leaving_day)) over (order by tfullname) 
   else max(leaving_day)
   end as leaving_time
   
   
FROM dbo.Sheet
group by arrival_date ,leaving_date ,tFullName
```

I wrote this to get the min hour between two hours group by date

```
case 
   when datepart(hh, min(arival_day)) between 00 and 05 
      then (select min(arival_day) 
            from dbo.Sheet 
            where datepart(hh, arival_day) not between 00 and 05 
            group by arrival_date) 
      else 
          min(arival_day)   
end arrival_time
```

and I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I change it without writing top 1 near the select (because it doesn't help) to get the min hours between 2 hours?

Thanks

Comment: Please post `dbo.Sheet` table with sample input data (in text format) and the expected output

Comment: You `GROUP BY arrival_date` and there is likely more than one distinct value for `arrival_date` in the subset satisfying the `WHERE`. That is, the subquery has more than one row but you have it in a place where only a scalar subquery (one row, one column) is allowed. Edit your question and post the whole query, along with a detailed description of what you're trying to achieve to get help with that. Please also post the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the tables involved along with sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements. Include the expected result with that sample data.

Comment: how can i insert a table? into the question

Comment: @O.Boiman Try with [this](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)